# Liferay rewrite resource-actions file

Tags: permissions, liferay, portlet

I need to edit default permissions of Liferay embeeded portlet (Polls). Configuration of resource actions and permisions for this liferay portlet is in ROOT/WEB-INF/portal-impl.jar/resource-actions/polls.xml.

Is it possible to rewrite this file in some other way than directly in portal-impl.jar? (Hook, Ext-plugin, portal-ext.properties...)

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: use ext-plugin to change polls.xml

Comment: Thanks for your answer - I have created ext plugin project and placed polls.xml into WEB-INF/ext-impl/src/resource-actions folder. Do I need to configure something else to make it work?

Comment: Looks good - @Pankaj: Why not add this as an answer, so that it can be accepted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I wrote in https://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/view_message/39208439.

This file is a part of *portal-impl.jar*, so you can do this only with EXT. Just copy updated *polls.xml* to folder *ext/extname/exname-ext-impl/src/main/resources/resource-actions/* (path for maven plugin) and deploy to your Liferay.

Regards,
KG

Answer (score 1):

Refer to link [Customizing and Extending Functionality with Hooks](https://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.2/development/-/ai/customize-and-extend-functionality-hooks-liferay-portal-6-2-dev-guide-en) for list of customization you can do with hook.

You should only use an Ext plugin if you are sure your customization is not achievable using a different tool.(portlet,hook,properties,configuration), so in your case, use ext-plugin to change polls.xml